# Symfony \ Component \ HttpKernel \ Exception \ MethodNotAllowedHttpException No message

Tags: laravel, routes

the following route when i submit a form is working fine

```
Route::put('/autorisation', 'AdministratifController@update_autorisation')->name('administartif.updateautorisation');
```

but i'm wondering why when i try to access `http://example.com/autorisation`
it throws

```
Symfony \ Component \ HttpKernel \ Exception \ MethodNotAllowedHttpException
No message
```

insted of page not found

it's not about the form it's about going to a browser and type `example.com/autorisation` and then u get that error of `no message` in place of 404

PS: in my routes i didn't define this `Route::get('/autorisation')`

Comment: Please check your method in form

Comment: i have POST on it the problem it's not about the form it's about going to a browser and type http://example.com/autorisation and then u get that error in place of 404

Answer (score 0):

By accessing the page yourself, you do a GET HTTP request instead of a PUT.

Answer (score 0):

You need to set the route as GET instead of PUT.

Answer (score 0):

Please change your route and try this:

```
Route::post('autorisation', 'AdministratifController@update_autorisation')->name('administartif.updateautorisation');
```

Answer (score 0):

You are defining the route as `PUT` but you are trying to use it like a `GET` route. That's why you are getting `MethodNotAllowed`.

If you want to show a 404 error instead this MethodNotAllowed (it would be a Whoops when `DEBUG=false`) you should handle it in your handler.

Edit `report` method at `App\Exceptions\Handler` to looks like this:

```
public function report(Exception $exception)
{
    if ($exception instanceof MethodNotAllowedHttpException) {
        abort(404, 'Page not found');
    }

    return parent::report($exception);
}
```